# Winston Ewert is no longer a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I've just now noticed the missing diamond on [his profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1659/winston-ewert), along with this:

[image]

There's no announcement on Meta, and this just seems like an abrupt change.  I'm not sure how long ago this was, either.  But I probably should've suspected something when it seemed to take a tad longer for my recent moderator flags to be reviewed.

I don't know too much about the moderator system, but I believe that the [Pro Tem moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) are appointed by SE.  Unfortunately, that means that SE is responsible for appointing another mod since we obviously cannot hold an election until graduation.  Overall, fewer active diamond mods is not good, even though this is a small (but growing) site.  Of course there are the SE employees ("universal" mods), but I don't think they're obligated to moderate Beta sites regularly.  Which is why Pro Tem mods are needed.

Could another moderator or anyone else weigh in on this?  If necessary, this could be migrated to MSO.  I'm just really surprised by this, considering such a change should be quickly known to the community.

Comment: +1 for the sad smiley :)

Comment: Would you volunteer?

Comment: Me?  Wow, I'm not entirely sure.  It is a goal of mine, albeit after graduation.  If SE chooses me, I'll accept.  If not, I'll be happy with anyone dedicated to help the site grow.

Comment: I became very active on the site just to try and make another high level member to help this site graduate to a full fledged site.  I approve Jamal and his Comments and his work on Code Review.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, I'm no longer a moderator. The deal is that I transitioned from being a grad student to a software engineer in the industry. As a result, I just don't have the same time to devote to being a moderator any more. As a result, I've stepped down as a moderator.

Being a moderator was a wonderful experience. I got to watch as Code Review grew from a site where there weren't enough votes to close any questions. But it seems that, at least for now, that time has come to a close. I am sad to have to move on from this role, but I'm sure that many members of this community will be able replacements.

Keep cleaning the code!

On the moderator front, I understand that the SE powers that will be looking to appoint a replacement (as they appointed me). They'll be looking for active and engaged users on code review to make that transition.

Comment: Thank you for your service. :-) I still remember when I posted my first (off-topic) question, and you were there to correct me.  You've done well here, and we'll continue on our path towards graduation.  Best wishes!

Comment: @Jamal, well, I'm really glad that of all those people I corrected about being off-topic at least one become a productive member of the site.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work gere. And good luck in your new position.