# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. As many of you know, one of your moderators [recently stepped down](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/winston-ewert-is-no-longer-a-moderator) for personal reasons. I'm happy to announce that a great new pro tem mod is about to take his place:

[image: Jamal]

Now, I could tell you about Jamal's contributions to the site, but it seems I don't need to, based on [the results of your recent informal election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/beta-site-in-need-of-new-moderator). So without further ado, please join me in welcoming Jamal, as well as thanking Winston for his service!

Comment: redundant congrats from me too! ;-)

Comment: I'm sad to have to leave, but I'm happy for you!

Answer (score 9):

## Congratulations Jamal!!

That diamond rocks!

> With great power, comes great responsibilities

Answer (score 6):

Hip Hip Hooray!

### Congratulations Jamal!

Comment: (flags as a duplicate) `</sarcasm>`